# Python - how to overcome Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable in order to put binary data into JSON

Tags: python, json, encoding

I've done this:-

```
try:
    with open(filename,'rb' ) as dat_file:
        foil = dat_file.read()
```

because my code reads *and repairs* arbitrary "text" files - in my analysis, some files have mixed line endings (caused by linux/mac people adding lines to DOS files) in the same file, and dozens of other nutty things...  anyhow - long story short - I must read the file as binary.

Now, if my repairs fail, I want to send a *verbatim* copy of what the file is (including all the stuffed up line ends, nulls, messed-up encodings, etc) to my server as JSON in a data post.

Therein lies the problem...

```
Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

What is the trick to putting binary data **of no encoding** into a JSON string?

Comment: Try `foil.decode('latin-1')` or `foil.decode('utf-8')` before you do json.dump

Answer (score 0):

@Jason Yang nailed it!  foil.decode('latin-1') did the trick!

(I tried a bunch before that, like 'ascii' and 'cp1252', all of which threw exceptions on assorted binary chars)

```
with open('all.256','rb' ) as dat_file:
    foil = dat_file.read()

test={}; test['data']=foil.decode('latin-1')
print(json.dumps(test))
```

outputs:

```
{"data": "\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\n\u000b\f\r\u000e\u000f\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a\u001b\u001c\u001d\u001e\u001f !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\u007f\u0080\u0081\u0082\u0083\u0084\u0085\u0086\u0087\u0088\u0089\u008a\u008b\u008c\u008d\u008e\u008f\u0090\u0091\u0092\u0093\u0094\u0095\u0096\u0097\u0098\u0099\u009a\u009b\u009c\u009d\u009e\u009f\u00a0\u00a1\u00a2\u00a3\u00a4\u00a5\u00a6\u00a7\u00a8\u00a9\u00aa\u00ab\u00ac\u00ad\u00ae\u00af\u00b0\u00b1\u00b2\u00b3\u00b4\u00b5\u00b6\u00b7\u00b8\u00b9\u00ba\u00bb\u00bc\u00bd\u00be\u00bf\u00c0\u00c1\u00c2\u00c3\u00c4\u00c5\u00c6\u00c7\u00c8\u00c9\u00ca\u00cb\u00cc\u00cd\u00ce\u00cf\u00d0\u00d1\u00d2\u00d3\u00d4\u00d5\u00d6\u00d7\u00d8\u00d9\u00da\u00db\u00dc\u00dd\u00de\u00df\u00e0\u00e1\u00e2\u00e3\u00e4\u00e5\u00e6\u00e7\u00e8\u00e9\u00ea\u00eb\u00ec\u00ed\u00ee\u00ef\u00f0\u00f1\u00f2\u00f3\u00f4\u00f5\u00f6\u00f7\u00f8\u00f9\u00fa\u00fb\u00fc\u00fd\u00fe\u00ff"}
```

Which happily decodes at the other end back into the exact right thing:

```
$ python3.7   python_unibin.py | perl -MJSON -ne 'chomp;$j=decode_json($_); print $j->{data}' | hexdump -C
00000000  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f  |................|
00000010  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f  |................|
00000020  20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27  28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f  | !"#$%&'()*+,-./|
00000030  30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37  38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f  |0123456789:;<=>?|
00000040  40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47  48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f  |@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO|
00000050  50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57  58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f  |PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_|
00000060  60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67  68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f  |`abcdefghijklmno|
00000070  70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77  78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e 7f  |pqrstuvwxyz{|}~.|
00000080  80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87  88 89 8a 8b 8c 8d 8e 8f  |................|
00000090  90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97  98 99 9a 9b 9c 9d 9e 9f  |................|
000000a0  a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7  a8 a9 aa ab ac ad ae af  |................|
000000b0  b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7  b8 b9 ba bb bc bd be bf  |................|
000000c0  c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7  c8 c9 ca cb cc cd ce cf  |................|
000000d0  d0 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7  d8 d9 da db dc dd de df  |................|
000000e0  e0 e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7  e8 e9 ea eb ec ed ee ef  |................|
000000f0  f0 f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7  f8 f9 fa fb fc fd fe ff  |................|
```